# jvm - total loaded classes vs loaded classes

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection

I am monitoring an application after JDK 11 upgrade from 8. What I found interesting is compare with JDK 8, JDK 11 has significantly increased `Total Loaded Classes` by time compared to JDK 8, despite the `Load Classes` is being steady.

Can I confirm if Loaded Classes count is being stable, then Total Loaded Classes raised over time should not be a concern as long as heap/non-heap memories are also being stable?

---Java 8--- (total loaded vs loaded seems to be unchanged over time)

[image]

----Java 11----

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which of the graphics is for which version of Java?

Comment: @aled Sorry I forgot to mention all pictures are generated by JDK 11 except the 1st one

Comment: presumably java 11 is more aggressive about unloading classes.  so you are probably seeing classes churn more over time.  but as long as your loaded classes is remaining stable, there shouldn't be any memory issues.

Comment: As long as metaspace is stable there is no issue. Classes are loaded into metaspace.